# too many flags (bitewise) - over 80(!!) error results

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, flags

I have a subsystem of a peripherals hardwares. Each peripheral can return few errors
The sub system indicates each error in a flag so when I call a method to check all the peripheral status it returns me a Uint64 code, which is a sum of all of the error codes

example

```
error1 = 1;
error2 = 2;
error3 = 4;
......
error7 = 64;
error8 = 128;
error9 = 256;
.......
```

so if i get a return code of 196 it mean i got error3,error8 and error 7 (4+64+128)

the number of total error can reach more than 50 errors and that's why the return code is Uint64

which the error64 can be a very large number(18446744073709551616), and can have more then 80 error in future reference

Is there a way to implement flag system when are more then 50 flags to check?

Comment: Do you *have* to do this all with one flag? Why not have a separate flag for each peripheral's error status?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. You just said your system uses a Uint64 for the flag. That means it supports 64 different error flags. You are asking if there is a way to store more than 50. Well, 64 > 50, so.... ? also, as computerfreaker mentioned, you can split errors from different devices into separate flag sets, then you could use normal integers to store those.

Comment: I can't , few error from diffrent peripherals can change the state of the server. so i need to consider all those error from one end point

Comment: Yeah. So, you wan ta 64 bit number without havinga 64 bit number? Do I get this right? "Too many numbers"? WHO CARES. Put it into an enum of Uint64 and be happy. What is the real problem, because right now you ask a logical fallacy.

Comment: OK, so you can't separate them in different sets. What of it? If all you need is around 50-55 errors, just use the Uint64.

Comment: @TomTom ... lol.... well i should care... what i'd had a system with more then 80 diffrent errors

Comment: I'm not getting it. If you need a set of flags for different purpose then create a separate object for it. If not, use bits 50-63.
You may use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx aswell

Comment: @nestedloop , again i can't separate the error per device. this will create a overhead on the other systems. It's quite a large system

Comment: @Izikon Oh, now I see you mentioned over 80 errors... that's different from the question. You said 50. Uint64 works for 50.

Comment: Exactly. Posting a question about "How do I handle 50 errosrs ina uint64" is not the same as 80. Standardize. Seriously. Code, Subcode - subcode is device specific.

Comment: Then what do you expect? You're using basic clr value type for storing some primitive info about an error and now you want to expand it without modifying the system? You want to hold more data in 64-bit value? How would you imagine that working? You're assumptions are wrong - system needs to be restandarized.

Comment: @Izikon, please edit your question to ask for how to store more than 64 or 65 or 70 flags. It will eliminate the logical fallacy, and you won't get any more -1's from people.

Comment: Stupid question - why flags? I mean, really. How many parallel errors you expect? Every other system I Know goes with an error code OR an array of error codes (if multiple may appear at the same time). Bitflags for errors - show me a precedence please for general use. I use that for stuff like connection status where I have a SMALL number of LOGICAL connections (data, orders, servers) for fast checks with arrays of active error codes for the details.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give a mechanism for storing more than 64 errors with a Uint64 Enum.

```
public enum MyFlag : UInt64
{
   control = 1,
   error1 = 2,
   error2 = 4,
   error3 = 8,
   //.......
   error63 = 9223372036854775808
}
```

This is the enum. Observe that we reserve the least significant bit for a control bit.

This means we can now have 63*2 = 126 different codes.

The drawback is that instead of the usual check, for instance:

```
resultFlag & MyFlag.error3
```

we will need to make a composite check, like:

```
resultFlag & MyFlag.error3 && resultFlag & MyFlag.control
```

or:

```
resultFlag & MyFlag.error3 && resultFlag%2
```

I hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

you can create enum:

```
[Flags] enum Errors {error1 =1,error2=2,error3=4, error4=8}
```

and then when you get answer from your subsystem just do that.

```
var MyNewError = 11;
Errors DecodedErrors = (Errors)MyNewError;
```

and then you will get fast list of all errors by converting DecodedErrors to string.

```
 Console.WriteLine(DecodedErrors.ToString());
 //output: error1, error2, error4
```

Combine it with @nestedloop solution and you are in home.